# How to cast a character set into a date format in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, casting, substring

When I try to cast a character set to the date format i get an error saying, `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string` I used the following query,

```
SELECT TOP 1 FileName
    FROM #myFiles order by
    cast(
        (SUBSTRING(filename,23,4))+'-'+
        (SUBSTRING(filename,28,2))+'-'+
        (SUBSTRING(filename,30,2)) as date)
    desc
```

On the following records,

```
sfd_devtracker_back_2017_04_02_094339_4242105.bak
sfd_devtracker_back_2017_04_03_094339_4242105.bak
sfd_devtracker_back_2017_04_04_094339_4242105.bak
```

What am i doing wrong here? Is my date format correct?

Comment: Not sure why you need to cast it to a date. since it's in YYYYMMDD format, and zeros are filled in ordering by just that part of of the string would suffice... `Order by substring(filename,21,10)` or `Order by substring(filename,21,25)`  plus if you have an invalid date entry the sql will not bomb out on the convert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option...

```
Declare @S varchar(max)='sfd_devtracker_back_2017_04_02_094339_4242105.bak'

Select try_convert(date,replace(substring(@S,charindex('_20',@S)+1,10),'_','-'))
```

Returns

```
2017-04-02
```

**For the table**

```
Declare @YourTable table (FileName varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('sfd_devtracker_back_2017_04_02_094339_4242105.bak'),
('sfd_devtracker_back_2017_04_03_094339_4242105.bak'),
('sfd_devtracker_back_2017_04_04_094339_4242105.bak')

Select Top 1 *
 From  @YourTable
 Order By try_convert(date,replace(substring(FileName,charindex('_20',FileName)+1,10),'_','-')) Desc
```

Returns

```
sfd_devtracker_back_2017_04_04_094339_4242105.bak
```

> **EDIT Actually, no need to convert to date**

```
Order By substring(FileName,charindex('_20',FileName)+1,10) Desc
```

Comment: thank you @JohnCappelletti. I managed to do my task without converting to date format with your help!

Comment: @NisalMalindaLivera Happy it helped.  After looking at it for a second time, it dawned on my that conversion was not necessary   cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You were a little off on the numbers. Here's another option:

```
SELECT CAST(
    (SUBSTRING('sfd_devtracker_back_2017_04_04_094339_4242105.bak',21,4))+'-'+
    (SUBSTRING('sfd_devtracker_back_2017_04_04_094339_4242105.bak',26,2))+'-'+
    (SUBSTRING('sfd_devtracker_back_2017_04_04_094339_4242105.bak',29,2)) AS date) DT
    ,FileName
ORDER BY DT DESC
```